# trouble connecting to VNC on GCP over mobile data

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, vnc

I have a VNC server running on a GCP instance and I can connect to it using my internet at home.  When I try to connect to it using mobile data (cellphone hotspot or a SIM card in my laptop), the VNC connection fails.   I can ping the remote computer (GCP instance) over the mobile data network and I can SSH into it using the button in GCP console, but VNC connection fails with this message:

"Error in TightVNC Viewer: A connection attempt failed because the connected part did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond."

I am using TightVNC.  My google search has only resulted in pages that talks about tunneling VNC connection through SSH which I have tried but couldn't make it work.

One additional note, in the settings for vnc server on GCP console, I have limited the IP addresses that can connect to VNC to only a few IPs to avoid trolls that attempt to break in from different IPs which would trip the firewall connection attempt limit and block all connections.  So when I use a new network, Wifi or a mobile network, I add the new IP assigned to my laptop to that list.  This has to be an IPv4 address and IPv6 type addresses (in case of mobile networks) are refused on GCP console settings.

Does anyone know what the problem is and how to solve it?  I don't see any firewall settings for the vnc server on GCP console, but I may just be missing it.